# How to reduce long table contents text size

Tags: longtable

I have created the following table for Overleaf. However, I want to use the `\tiny` or `\scriptsize` because this table spans several pages. I must also maintain the color scheme. I have tried numerous times and sought help from ChatGPT, but it has not worked. Is there any way that without losing the table look, I can reduce the size.

```
\begin{longtable}{
    |c
    |>{\columncolor{blue!10}}p{2cm}
    |>{\columncolor{blue!10}}p{4cm}
    |>{\columncolor{green!10}}p{2cm}
    |>{\columncolor{green!10}}p{4cm}|
}

% Apply the caption and label outside of the tiny environment
\caption{Automation Challenges and Solution framework for containerized applications in multi-cloud environment}\label{tab:Automation-solutions} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50} 
\textbf{ID} & 
\textbf{Challenge} & 
\textbf{Challenge Description} & 
\textbf{Solution} & 
\textbf{Solution Description} \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead

% The content above will serve as the header for the first page.
% Content below will serve as the header for the continuation pages.
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50} 
\textbf{ID} & 
\textbf{Challenge} & 
\textbf{Challenge Description} & 
\textbf{Solution} & 
\textbf{Solution Description} \\ 
\hline
\endhead

% Footer for all pages except the last, if you want one.
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\hline
\endfoot

% Footer for the last page, if you want one.
\hline
\endlastfoot

% Now insert your table rows here, with the tiny size applied
\tiny % Apply the font size to the content starting from here
\rowcolor{gray!25} \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Category 1: Multi-Cloud Automation}} \\
\hline
% ... more rows of content ...

% End the tiny environment before the table ends
\normalsize % Switch back to normal size text if needed after the table

\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709895/how-to-reduce-long-table-contents-text-size) twice. If you want to change your question (e.g. add formatting as leandriis does) you should edit your question but don't ask it newly.